# Python Turtle checking for bounds (not working)

Tags: python, graphics, geometry

I have a program where there is a box of BOUNDING_UNITS. Now ,I have to draw triangles inside the box in a random fashion. (random orientation). 
However, for some reason, the triangles are going outside the box.

This is what its looking like :
[image]

The correct solution would be to have all the three points of the triangle inside the square box.

This are  functions :

```
def doTriangles(num):
    if num<=0:
        return
    isColliding =True

    while isColliding:

        goingX=random.randint(-1*BOUNDING_BOX(),BOUNDING_BOX())
        goingY=random.randint(-1*BOUNDING_BOX(),BOUNDING_BOX())
        newDir = random.randint(1,60)
        newLen=200


        isColliding =checkForCollision(newLen,goingX,goingY,newDir)

        if isColliding == False:
            up()
            goto(goingX,goingY)
            setheading(newDir)
            down()
            doOneTriangle(newLen)





    doTriangles(num-1)

    print("hold me")








def checkForCollision(len,positionX,positionY,heading):

    up()

    x=int(xcor())
    y=int(ycor())
    pprint.pprint(locals())

    if x>=BOUNDING_BOX():
        goto(positionX,positionY)
        setheading(heading)
        return True
    elif x<=-1*BOUNDING_BOX():
        goto(positionX,positionY)
        setheading(heading)
        return True
    elif y>=BOUNDING_BOX():
        goto(positionX,positionY)
        setheading(heading)
        return True
    elif y<=-1*BOUNDING_BOX():
        goto(positionX,positionY)
        setheading(heading)
        return True


    up()
    right(90)
    fd(len/2)


    x=int(xcor())
    y=int(ycor())
    pprint.pprint(locals())

    if x>=BOUNDING_BOX():
        goto(positionX,positionY)
        setheading(heading)
        return True
    elif x<=-1*BOUNDING_BOX():
        goto(positionX,positionY)
        setheading(heading)
        return True
    elif y>=BOUNDING_BOX():
        goto(positionX,positionY)
        setheading(heading)
        return True
    elif y<=-1*BOUNDING_BOX():
        goto(positionX,positionY)
        setheading(heading)
        return True






    left(120)

    fd(len)


    x=int(xcor())
    y=int(ycor())
    pprint.pprint(locals())

    if x>=BOUNDING_BOX():
        goto(positionX,positionY)
        setheading(heading)
        return True
    elif x<=-1*BOUNDING_BOX():
        goto(positionX,positionY)
        setheading(heading)
        return True
    elif y>=BOUNDING_BOX():
        goto(positionX,positionY)
        setheading(heading)
        return True
    elif y<=-1*BOUNDING_BOX():
        goto(positionX,positionY)
        setheading(heading)
        return True






    left(120)
    fd(len)


    x=int(xcor())
    y=int(ycor())
    pprint.pprint(locals())

    if x>=BOUNDING_BOX():
        goto(positionX,positionY)
        setheading(heading)
        return True
    elif x<=-1*BOUNDING_BOX():
        goto(positionX,positionY)
        setheading(heading)
        return True
    elif y>=BOUNDING_BOX():
        goto(positionX,positionY)
        setheading(heading)
        return True
    elif y<=-1*BOUNDING_BOX():
        goto(positionX,positionY)
        setheading(heading)
        return True
    else:
        goto(positionX,positionY)
        setheading(heading)
        print("I RETURNED FALSE  ")
        return False





def doOneTriangle(len):



    up()
    right(90)
    fd(len/2)
    down()
    left(120)

    #begin_fill()
    fd(len)
    left(120)
    fd(len)
    left(120)
    fd(len)
    left(120)
    fd(len)
    right(30)

   # end_fill()
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Whar happens when one of the first two points is False?  Also, you have redundant code.  The if x>= etc code should be in a separate function that you pass x and y to.

Answer (score 0):

I know very little about turtle but it looks like you are comparing one x/y value and plotting another value, but it may also be my lack of knowledge

```
x=int(xcor())
y=int(ycor())
pprint.pprint(locals())

if x>=BOUNDING_BOX():         ## using x
    goto(positionX,positionY) ## using positionX
    setheading(heading)
    return True
```